# Which database for chat logging?

Tags: database

I'm implementing a chat system.

What kind of database I should use for logging chat messages?

I need to do some queries to it. For example "give me all the links from user x between these dates"

I've [heard](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging) some good things about MongoDB for this kind of stuff. How about other NoSQL solutions? Redis? Cassandra?

How about old SQL solutions? Although I'm very interested having experiences with NoSQL-databases, but I'm not going to it just sake of it :)

I need to be able to handle hundreds of active users.

Comment: You need to mention your scale.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So basically NoSQL is not a panacea. You really have to know the sweet spot for each NoSQL to gain maximum benefit of it.

For your scenario I would recommend mongodb. Why? Because mongodb offer very rich query just as you would have in SQL database, unlike key-value store database. Mongodb is relatively fast in both write and read.

Unless you need massive scalability like facebook or twitter, cassandra is not for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SQLite](http://sqlite.org) for this type of logging in the past and it's worked a treat.

Comment: Doesn't it suffer from write locks? Since in chat systems you'll be getting whole bunch of writes.

Answer (score 0):

I consider that you are not a google or a twitter ;) just use mysql, sqlite or any relational database. This should completely suffice for you, but if it don't then think about nosql solutions, not now.

Comment: Why? Are those easier or what? I have no problem learning new database systems. I would actually like to do so.

Comment: nosql is a new trend it isn't complete examined. If you want just to do it for testing (on non-production environment) then go on.

Comment: You don't have to be twitter or google to use NoSQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend document stores like *CouchDB*. Have a look at some NoSQL solutions [here](http://nosql-databases.org/).

Comment: Hmm, the REST API is basically free and writing CouchDB views in JavaScript is fun :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Cassandra. I find it easier to develop for than even MySQL, though there is a little bit of learning curve. Dealing with schema changes is a real pain in production environments with MYSQL, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

My vote goes out to redis(+node). I can handle that scale easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine by the following ways :

If your data is simple and small, you could consider using **SQLite**, it is easy to integrate with either web app, mobile app or desktop application and it is light weight.

check http://www.sqlite.org/

If the data is big, consider **NOSQL** databases, such as

**MongoDB** http://www.mongodb.org/

or

**HBase** https://hbase.apache.org/

If you are familiar with windows and , consider **MYSQL** or **MSSQL**